# Прозрачный фон в живых обоях android

Tags: android, java

Никто не подскажет как сделать? Или пойти по другому пути, что бы рабочий стол оставался пользователя, а все что должно происходить в обоях происходило на имеющемся рабочем столе. На пример как это сделано вот [тут](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.commind.bubbles&feature=order_history#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDUwMCwiY29tLmNvbW1pbmQuYnViYmxlcyJd) в обоях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос совершенно неясен... Управление обоями программно происходит через [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html). Весь набор действий, который можно произвести с обоями описан там в документации, читайте и думайте.

Comment: А че собсно не понятного, можно ли сделать что бы обои отрисовывались на рабочем столе который был раньше, как по ссылке приведенной в вопросе.